# Is the copy editor badge not working?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

According to [the description of the copy editor badge](https://apple.stackexchange.com/badges/33/copy-editor), the requirement is for you to edit 500 posts. I have done that and I don't see the badge. If you look on [the users page](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users?tab=editors&filter=all), you'll notice that both bmike and I have edited more than 500 posts. Why don't I have a badge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few potential reasons:

- You seem to have recently crossed over the threshold, so the badge simply hasn't been awarded yet. Some badges aren't awarded immediately, but instead with a batch script that's run daily.
- You edit a lot of tag wikis. It's possible that the /users page tracks *all* edits, but the badge only counts edits to posts.
- Maybe only edits to the *content* of a post are considered for the badge, and while you have 500 edits some are editing the tags of a question instead of the actual content of the post.

These are just speculations, but I'll bet that at least one is true. Just keep editing, you'll get it eventually :)

Comment: Might the badge only count approved edits while the user page reports suggested edits?

Comment: Ok, thanks! It just didn't make sense to me when I saw it.

Comment: I just got the badge.

Answer (score 1):

It has been stated in meta.so ([Is the number of edits on the users page the one relevant for the edit badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108816/is-the-number-of-edits-on-the-users-page-the-one-relevant-for-the-edit-badges)) that the edits count in the users page is *not* relevant for the edit badges. It is said to exclude trivial edits, but [it has not been officially stated which are trivial](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81655/what-kind-of-edits-are-counted-in-userstab-editors).

Just recently a counter has been added to the right pane of the [review](https://apple.stackexchange.com/review/) page, which shows your progress on edits:

[image: review progress]

Reflecting the edit count on the review page to the one on the users page; I can say that **retags** aren't counted for badges while they are counted on the users page — just checked this.

Comment: Err, I don't see this counter on the review page?!

Comment: @patrix maybe it is then only shown to those who are working towards Strunk & White.

Comment: Well, it turned up in the meantime.

Comment: @patrix yes there must've been some modifications as also I see the badge process towards Copy editor (and Electorate), which weren't there earlier.